# What connector should I use to connect LED light / driver to mains?

Tags: lighting, led

I've just got some LED spots to go in a small cloakroom. What connector should I use to connect them to the mains? The mains wires to the driver are tiny (about 20AWG).

[image]

Is there are recommended connector for these, or should I just use Choc-blocks?

Comment: I think in the UK you guys typically use terminal blocks, right? Why do you think they are not applicable to this situation?

Comment: It's not that I don't think they're applicable - just wondered if there was a better solution. Was just thrown by how tiny the wires were as I guess I'll have 2 x 1mm^2 mains cable on one side and this flimsy wire on the other.

Comment: By the way - just spotted these, which look ideal. Do you have something similar in the US? http://www.edwardes.co.uk/en/products/hager-ashley-j501-16a-4-way-downlight-junction-box (or these are pretty cool too: http://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Images/Products/size_3/TLCT100C.JPG)

Comment: Those are pretty neat. We don't have stuff like that in the US, because we're not afraid of twist-on wire connectors.

Comment: I personally don't like terminal blocks because the screws can damage the wires. I would use crimp connectors or twist on connectors with a couple of wraps of electrical tape, ('cos I live in the US!)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use wire nuts to attach those to standard lamp cord, and put a standard plug at the other end...

Comment: [Nobody in the UK uses wire nuts (twist-on wire connectors)](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/10144/33). They think they're crap, and cause wires to spontaneously combust or something.

Comment: Also... You'll have an exposed splice with no strain relief, which sounds dangerous.

Comment: The fixture shown in the photo is intended for mounting through a hole in a panel. I presume wiring would be behind said panel. If the querant is doing something else, we need more detail.

Comment: If you don't like wirenuts, you could use crimp connections. Or terminal blocks, but that's far more "exposed" than a wirenut splice.

Comment: From what you posted, I pictured [something like this](http://i.imgur.com/HuqhMND.png).

Comment: Electrically, yes. Physically, I'm presuming (a) a long piece of [zip cord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip-cord) will be needed to reach the power supply, and (b) that this isn't going to simply be stapled to the wall -- or at the very least, will be attached to the cloakroom's ceiling so the splice will be out of reach. ("Out of sight, out of mind," said the blind maniac.)